# When to use jacket,cloak and sweater?

Tags: vocabulary

Sweater probably means a mini jacket ,one that covers the TOP half of your body.
Jacket is prob okay one that you use in cold environments and is casual wear
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak
Cloak means like a bigger jacket like one in a Harry Potter movie
I think you classify them in terms of size then

Comment: Cloaks are generally associated with magicians, vampires, and superheroes.  They must have been more widely worn at one time, though, since a "cloakroom" is a room where you hang up your jacket or coat (and can also be a euphemism for a toilet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sweater is usually a knitted garment that you pull on over your head.

A jacket is an upper body garment that opens at the front. It may be the upper half of a man's suit, a similar garment for women, or an outer garment.

A cloak doesn't have sleeves, it is draped over the shoulders. A full-length outer garment with sleeves is a *coat* or *overcoat.*

Comment: so you mean sweater has a hood?

Comment: No, I mean that it doesn't unfasten at the front, so you have to pull the neck of the garment over your head before putting your arms into the sleeves.